# Problem in including an external library while compiling a C++ program

Tags: compiler-construction, g++, winpcap

I'm using Dev C++ on windows 7, and WinPcap (developer's pack). Dev c++ is not able to find pcap.h apparently, even though I include the /include/ directory in project options, on compilation it displays an error saying "pcap.h: no such file or directory." (along with many other errors).
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pcap.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
pcap_t *fp;
char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
u_char packet[100];

    return 0;
}
```

I've kept it simple. I was originally working in Visual Studio (C++), but distributing code compiled with Visual C++ requires Microsoft C Runtime library to be installed on the target system. I just want to be able to distribute the final executable and get it to work on any machine.

I checked the commmand line given to compiler. It **did** have the -I [path] option. Well is there anything I'm missing?

As a side note: I had compiled the above code with g++ (from dev c++ installation dir), and it compiled correctly. But when I tried to link it, the executable produced, just crashed on being run.

Comment: Did you include the /lib or /bin folders in your project options as well?  They will typically be listed as "library folder" or something to do with the linker.  Unless you're compiling from source, you need the development libraries (e.g. for VS, the .lib files to go with the source code of that library).

Comment: Yes I had included that as well. Library dir. and Include dir. in the project options. But its still not being able to find the header file.

Comment: are you using the Visual Studio library files or the MinGW/Cygwin library files?

Comment: MinGW. I wanna remain as far as possible from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear, but your side-note makes it sound as if you could compile this (i.e. the `pcap.h` header was found) and your issues is with linking.

To add directories to the search path for libraries use `-LPATH` where `PATH` is the actual directory containing `libpcap`. To actually add it to the link use `-lpcap` in the linker call, e.g.

```
$ g++ -o main -LPATH main.o -lpcap
```

Comment: @Employed: I fixed it, I attribute that brain-damaged error to using build systems for too long (which I am happy about -- the using part).